# Is a 1960's flask safe to use every day?

Tags: health

I've got a 1960's flask. Can it still be used safely?

It's in very good condition with no rust or flaking at all. I've cleaned it well and it seems to be OK.

Comment: Welcome to outdoors.SE! I improved your question a bit, I hope you agree with that. Do you have any additional details on the flask? For example, what material is it made of, is there any plastic coating on the inside, etc? Pictures might also help here, though I'm not an expert on food safety.

Comment: Hi Andreas,yes that fine thanks,I'll try and put some photos up asap.

Comment: What sort of flask? Vacuum flask? They used to be glass and are now stainless so should last indefinitely unless damaged.

Comment: Hi Chris, the inside is glass the outside is metal,taken photos but can't work out how to post them on here

Comment: Hmm not sure a flask of any age is safe to drink *every* day ;)

Comment: Might be helpful if you could explain exactly what you mean by 'flask'.  I've only seen the word used (in modern language) for scientific glassware, or a pocket-sized bottle used to carry booze during Prohibition days - neither of which seems to have much relevance to outdoors :-)

Answer (score 2):

My parents have routinely used old flasks for many years with no ill effects.

As the flask is metal / glass both of which can be sterilised I expect it would be fine to use. I recommend you check the seal in the lid which keeps it watertight. If this is rubber it is likely to be degraded and could leak and, as rubber is porous, is a potential hiding place for bacteria etc. There is less risk if the seal is plastic.

Before the first use I would fully immerse the whole flask in a mild bleach solution to sterilise it. Use a baby bottle solution, not household bleach. Follow the instructions on the baby solution and you should be fine.

After every use make sure you wash the flask and dry it out completely before using again the next day. Periodically sterilise it as above to keep any lingering bugs at bay.